# Calculate average points per seond

Tags: python, time-series, timestamp

my problem is that I have an n-point time-series and want to know how many points are in a second on average.
My points are T0, T1, ..., Tn-1. in nanoseconds.
They are ascending Ti > Ti-1 and T0 >= 0

This problem should have already been solved, but I can't find it.

my approach is:
`10⁹ / (Tn-1 - T0)/n`
but when i try it on paper it doesn't make sense.

```
Answer:
n * 10e-9 / (Tn-1 - T0)
```

Thank you.

Comment: your times are in nanoseconds, you need to **multiply** by 10e9 to convert to seconds.  then divide by n points.  you will then have the average duration. Make the inverse to know how many fit in one second. so at the end the equation will look like `n * 10e-9 / (Tn-1 - T0)`

Comment: thank you.
i am new here, can i somehow flag this question as answered?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can write the comment as an answer and you can then accept it if that answer worked for you. Let me know